# Javascript toString overwrite function return type

Tags: javascript

I'm a novice to JavaScript programming language and currently learning about closures. I know that if we alert the function which return a function, we will see the source code of the returning function:

```
function sum(a) {
  var sum = a
 function f(b) {
    sum += b
    return f
  }
  f.toString = function() { return sum }
  return f
}

var a=sum(2)(2)(2)(2); //why this sum function return sum
                       //instead of function f source code
alert(a);
```

In that above code, why does the function `sum()` return inner scope variable `sum` instead of returning function `f` source code. Does `toString` function overwrite the return type of function `sum()`?

Comment: not directly related to your question, but IMHO you're asking for trouble by having a variable and the enclosing function with the same name (and it smells like certain versions of BASIC)

Answer (score 0):

`alert(a)` will call `a.toString()` and display its result.

The default function `toString()` (`Function.prototype.toString`) returns the function's source.

If you replace it with your own `toString()`, it will return whatever your function returns.

Comment: Thank you for your attention sir..but why the below function return "Hello!" instead of "Hi".I have replaced my own toString .       function f(){
                 return "Hello!";
                    f.toString=function(){
                     return "Hi!";   
                    }
                }
                var a=f();
                alert(a);//Hello

Comment: @DevMini: You're calling the function, not its `toString`.  Calling a function that returns `"Hello!"` will, by definition, return `"Hello!"`